# AWS Lamdba Version delete Using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

IS it possible to delete the AWS Lambda using CloudFormation templates and also the versions. I tried looking at CustomResource documentation, but seems we have to delete the stack to delete the main Lambda?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a side note. I've noticed that almost all your questions have answers, but non was accepted, even though in comments you write that the answer solved your issue. Please accept good answers, as this helps others in future with similar questions and prevents from making duplicate questions for same/similar issues.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, i'm new it so i don't know how to accept the answers

Comment: Check your past answers, and under upvoate/downvote buttons there is "tick" button to accept. You can also up vote them if you want.

Comment: Yeah, i accepted the answers for my past requests

Answer (score 2):

Generally you can delete lambda version using, for example, AWS API [delete-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565380/aws-lamdba-version-delete-using-cloudformation):

> To delete a specific function version, use the Qualifier parameter. Otherwise, all versions and aliases are deleted.

In case of CloudFormation, you have to just **remove your** `AWS::Lambda::Version` from your template, and **update** the stack. The update will delete the version created, without removing the lambda function.

Comment: Are you referring to this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_DeleteFunction.html ? I have the Lambda version already created manually, and would like to delete it now through cloudformation,

Comment: @JASPHI If you created it manually, then without a custom resource you want be able to delete them. The only other alternative is to [import the version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html) into cloudformation. And then you can mange its lifetime from CFN.

Comment: @JASPHI How did it go with this issue?